# Check if a string can be converted to another type (C#)

Tags: c#, types, enums

I'm doing some testing things in C#, and I now need to know something. I create a class, like that:

```
class DChanger
{
    //Just ignore this:
    private string section = Csuc.CPanel.CPanelSection.Appearance;
    //Then the constructor: DChanger dchange = new DChanger(Internet);
    public void DChanger(string subsection)
    {
        //Code
    }
}
```

So, now. I want to check if "subsection" can be converted to another type. In example, i'd had an enum:

```
enum Subsections { Internet, Programming };
```

And I want to check if "subsection" is "Internet" or "Programming" (in this example, because the real enum has got a lot of more sections). 
Could I do that? Thankyou!

Comment: Put a new line between your text and code indenting to get it to format correctly :)

Comment: Oops, sorry. You saved my format!

Comment: can you use TryParse() ?

Comment: Are you specifically asking about enumerations? What about other types?

Comment: or are you just talking about about comparing a string to a string in an enum of strings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to test quick it is better to test with Enum class it:

```
public void DChanger(string subsection)
    {
       bool b = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Subsections)).Contains(subsection);
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use Enum.Parse and watch for an exception of type ArgumentException.
You can also use Enum.TryParse.

More info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx

Comment: ... and preferred. Don't use exceptions to control flow if you can help it.